# Windows Xp login problem

Tags: windows, windows-xp, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP login problem after changing network settings to join WORKGROUP](https://superuser.com/questions/213443/windows-xp-login-problem-after-changing-network-settings-to-join-workgroup)

I was able to login on Windows Xp(I choose domain and enter user/pass). But now you lan networks has changed and i changed Identification of my laptop to join homenetwork and to be in WORKGROUP. After i reboot i'm not able to login with my user/pass...

Could anybody suggest what to do? Do my user password was setted to some default value?

Thx

Comment: *lan networks has changed and i changed Identification of my laptop to join homenetwork and to be in WORKGROUP* -- after which change did the problem start?

Comment: after i changed to be in WORKGROUP

Comment: As this question is on Super User twice now: could you please click "close" and vote for closing this very question?