# Windows XP login problem after changing network settings to join WORKGROUP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I was able to login on Windows Xp (I choose domain and enter user/pass). But now you lan networks has changed and i changed Identification of my laptop to join homenetwork and to be in WORKGROUP. After i reboot i'm not able to login with my user/pass...

Could anybody suggest what to do? Do my user password was setted to some default value?

Comment: Might be better asking at superuser.com

Comment: if you are in a workgroup, you need a local user account on your computer to be able to log in. Either that or the Administrator password to be able to log in as "Administrator"

Comment: @Elliott, please don't tell people to post again. That will just get us duplicates, like http://superuser.com/questions/213441/windows-xp-login-problem

Answer (score 1):

After leaving the domain you can no longer use your domain credentials, simple as that. Your computer will not try to authenticate with a domain controller, so you are forced to log in with a local user account.

I don't know what you mean by "lan network has changed" but if your computer is on a different physical network, that is an additional problem. You cannot contact the proper domain controller on a different LAN (unless you have VPN or similar), and your cached credentials won't work any more anyways.

You're best off going back to the old network and rejoining the domain. If this is not your machine, give it to someone in your IT department and tell them what happened. You shouldn't have been able to leave the domain without supplying domain admin credentials though...